# Time complexity of go functions like strings.Cut and strings.Contains

Tags: go

Is there any way from the go documentation or anyway to know time complexity of built in go functions like strings? Cut, strings. Contains without going through the actual implementation and figuring our ourselves.

Comment: Use a tool. There are also IDE extensions to determine complexity. Use a popular search engine to find them.

Comment: Write benchmarks to determine that, it is a common practice used in the language - https://pkg.go.dev/testing#hdr-Benchmarks

Comment: Are your inputs for string and pattern that large that it actually matters? Or is this a purely academic question?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way from the go documentation or anyway to know time complexity of built in go functions like strings.Cut, strings.Contains without going through the actual implementation and figuring our ourselves.

No.

Some packages document something in that direction (e.g. package sort documents how many calls are made to Less and Swap) but package strings doesn’t. (Given that time complexity of Cut is pretty obvious for all nonpathological uses this seems okay).